# KnockoutJS - select/dropbox not populating

Tags: json, knockout.js

I have a set of four cascading  select boxes that are driven by JSON. Depending on nested data being available, a dropbox appears, *populated* or not... all working fine except the last level.. I cant see whats wrong but I'm sure its something obvious...

First of all my bindings .. I am using the "if:..." to determine if to show the next cascading / nested dropbox or not...

```
<select id="cboSpecies" data-bind="options: SearchCriteria.Species, optionsText: 'Name', value: Species, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
<div data-bind="if: Species">
  <select data-bind='options: Species().System, optionsText: "Name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: System'></select>
</div>
<div data-bind="if: System">
  <select data-bind='options: System().Syndrome, optionsText: "Name", optionsCaption: "Select...", optionsValue: "Name", value: Syndrome'></select>
</div>
<div data-bind="if: Syndrome">
  <select data-bind='options: Syndrome().Diagnosis, optionsText: "Name", optionsCaption: "Select...", optionsValue: "Name", value: Diagnosis'></select>
</div>
```

Next my knockout code:

```
function SearchModel() {
  this.SearchCriteria = "";
  this.Species = ko.observable();
  this.System = ko.observable();
  this.Syndrome = ko.observable();
  this.Diagnosis = ko.observable();
}

var model = new SearchModel();
model.SearchCriteria = json;
```

Finally the JSON string itself..

```
var json = {
  "Species": [{
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "Feline",
    "System": []
  }, {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Ovine",     
    "System": []
  }, {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "Canine",
    "System": [{
      "ID": 1,
      "Name": "Cardiovascular System",
      "Syndrome": [{
          "ID": 1,
          "Name":"Blood",
          "Diagnosis":[
              {
               "Name": "Diag 1"},
              {
               "Name": "Diag 2"
                  }]
              },
                   {
          "ID": 2,
          "Name": "Heart/Aorta",
          "Diagnosis":[{"Name": "Diag 3"}          
          ]}]
    },{
      "ID": 1,
      "Name": "GI System /Abdomen",
      "Syndrome": [
            {
          "ID": 1,
          "Name":"Abdomen",
          "Diagnosis":[]
            },
           {
          "ID": 2,
          "Name":"Abomasum",
          "Diagnosis":[]
          }]
    }]
  }]  
};
```

Everything works fine until the last dropbox which is not getting populated...

[image: screenshot showing dropbox not populating]

I have a fiddle of it here:

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qtime67/J73Q5/)

To test, select "Canine", then "Cardiovascular", then "Blood".
I expect the final dropbox to have data "Diag 1" and "Diag 2"

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`optionsValue` parameter is redundant in `System` selector:

```
<div data-bind="if: System">
  <select data-bind='options: System().Syndrome, optionsText: "Name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: Syndrome'></select>
</div>
```

[**Fixed JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zg9n/)

Comment: Beat me to it : )  Nice to mention the reason you need to do this is because it binds to the value of 'Name' instead of the object, and the Name has no 'Diagnosis's

Comment: Many thanks IIla, and also PW Pad and Timothy for the reason!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of `optionsValue: "Name"` on the `Syndrome` select (and there's no reason to have it on the `Diagnosis` select). The problem is that, if the `optionsValue` for `Syndrome` is `"Name"`, the `optionsValue` is pointing to a `string` property of each `Syndrome`. That string property doesn't have a `Diagnosis` member. So you are then trying to bind your `Diagnosis` select to an `undefined`, which results in a `Diagnosis` select with no options.

Comment: Why a downvote? My answer is correct, and it goes deeper to explain what the problem was rather than just saying "`optionsValue` is redundant." It's not redundant, it's wrong, and I explain why.